Eas build IOS app failed but expo run ios passed
I have updated an application to version expo SDK 46,when I run the local code using thenpx expo run:ios command, everything works perfectly.
But when I run the command eas build --platform ios to build the respective application, it gives me the corresponding error:
The Swift pod `FirebaseCoreInternal` depends upon `GoogleUtilities`, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

I modified the following files Podfile.
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print"require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/package.json')"`), "native_modules")

require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 
'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}

platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '12.4'
install! 'cocoapods',
:deterministic_uuids => false

target 'APP Name' do
  use_expo_modules!
  config = use_native_modules!

use_frameworks! :linkage => podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks'].to_sym if podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks']

pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

# Flags change depending on the env values.
flags = get_default_flags()

use_react_native!(
 :path => config[:reactNativePath],
 :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled] || podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes',
 :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
 # An absolute path to your application root.
 :app_path => "#{Dir.pwd}/.."
)

# Uncomment to opt-in to using Flipper
# Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work
#
# if !ENV['CI']
#   use_flipper!()
# end

post_install do |installer|
 react_native_post_install(installer)
  __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)

# This is necessary for Xcode 14, because it signs resource bundles by default
# when building for devices.
installer.target_installation_results.pod_target_installation_results
  .each do |pod_name, target_installation_result|
  target_installation_result.resource_bundle_targets.each do |resource_bundle_target|
    resource_bundle_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
 end
 end

 post_integrate do |installer|
 begin
   expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
 rescue => e
   Pod::UI.warn e
 end
 end
end

After I gave pod disintegrate, pod install and pod update, locally everything works fine but the problem appears when I give eas build

{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "expo start --dev-client"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^5.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "~15.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "~15.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "~15.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "~15.4.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.7",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^5.0.0",
    "expo": "~46.0.21",
    "expo-dev-client": "~1.3.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.7",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.9",
    "react-native-custom-checkbox": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.3.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.10.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^5.0.2",
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "^5.0.5"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "app name",
  "license": "GPL-3.0",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}

when I run the command npx expo doctor everything seems fine.

